# How to change the color of an image when getting points

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas

Currently I have a car game which I give points when a car touches the monster.Now extra to that I also wanted to change the color of the car or replace the car image with a different color car image when it is touching the monster.

So where I give point is

```
monsters.array.forEach(monster => {
            if(monster.isTouching(this)){
                monster.reset();
                monstersCaught += 1;
            }
        });
```

So now when I give point I also want to change the color of the car.
Any help is appreciated.My pen for the game :[pen](https://codepen.io/RKR3/project/editor/ANBVpA/)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 1 car image, you can use javascript to give the car a css property `hue-rotate()` to change its color.

If you have multiple car images with different colors, you can simply change the `src` attribute using javascript to point to the new car image.

Comment: I have multiple car images but I want to change the color when it hit the monster and change back to default after 5 seconds.Which way will be inappropriate `hue-rotate()` or change the src attribute

Comment: I  also updated my  pen. you can see where I have two different images and I want to  switch to `here_other` image when the car hits the monster